# Rails 6: JS bypassing the conditions, running code on each visit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to handle clicking on the back button using JS code mixed by the Rails. When the user goes to the payment page, the status of the item is changed ( to make double ordering and payment impossible) and when the user clicks on the back button, the status should be changed to the initial one again.

Here's the code to manage it by recognising the back button and a session that was set before:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      const perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType('navigation');
      if (perfEntries.length && perfEntries[0].type === 'back_forward') {
          console.log(perfEntries);
          <% if session[:payment] == 'true' %>
              <% @item.update(status: 'available') %>
          <% end %>
      }
    });
</script>
```

The problem is the JS condition is bypassed always and the `update` method is run on all the visits. So, no matter if back button is clicked or not, the item will be updated. I tried the inner `if` in JS, too, but still not working. Seems the only part which is working is Rails code not JS.

The question is what's the problem here? As I have JS code in other parts which is working well.
And, is there any better way to handle this situation? The `@item` should be updated only on backing from the payment page.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up JS code with Ruby template code. Whatever you place inside the `<% %>` tags will always get evaluated server-side while rendering the view.

What you should do is make an ajax call to the update_item service when the condition is met (all in JS)